# Get the top n rows of each day from same table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am sure this is not a novel/new problem. I really tried to look into other solutions. However, I could not find how to solve this.

I have a model like

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    viewCounter = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    thumbsUpCounter = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    createDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='deal_owner',
                          editable=False)
```

Now I want to get top 10 (or less) deals ordering by thumbsUpCounter and viewCounter  of every day. I tried to look into the Subquery and Outerref. However, I could not figure out how can I get the right results.

** I am using MySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to group by date, and find top 10 hits?

Comment: @ha-neul yes. that is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

query = Deal.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('createDateTime'))\ # extract date 
        .values('date')\                                        # group by date
        .order_by('-thumbsUpCounter')\                          # order by
         [:10]                                                  # slice first 10
```

Comment: could you please check the syntax? there are some syntax issues for braces.

Comment: yes, I missed one ```)``` in the first line. updated

Comment: really thanks for your answer. But I am getting an error 'dict' object has no attribute 'owner', owner is a another model of Deal model. Do you have any idea of this.

Comment: ? I don’t see owner anywhere in your q?

Comment: I did not realize that the foreign key would give any error. I added the owner.

Comment: First of all, if you print out the query, does it show top 10 that you want? Second, you have something like q.owner in your template?

Comment: It does not show the rows, it gives an error. I am using django rest, there is no template.

Comment: just to let you know.. your solution actually doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. were you able to print out ```print(query)``` in the terminal?

Comment: There is no grouping , how would that work anyway?

Comment: in django ORM, values is for grouping. we grouped by the date. when you say no grouping, could you be more specific?

Comment: I reposted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65324003/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-with-django-queryset