# Get top n records for each group with Django queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model like the following Table,

```
create table `mytable`
(
  `person` varchar(10),
  `groupname` int,
  `age` int
);
```

And I want to get the 2 oldest people from each group. The original SQL question and answers are here [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results) and One of the solutions that work is

```
SELECT
    person,
    groupname,
    age
FROM
(
    SELECT
        person,
        groupname,
        age,
        @rn := IF(@prev = groupname, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
        @prev := groupname
    FROM mytable
    JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
    ORDER BY groupname, age DESC, person
) AS T1
WHERE rn <= 2
```

You can check the SQL output here as well [SQLFIDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffe026)

I just want to know how can I implement this query in Django's views as queryset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another SQL with similar output would have window function that annotates each row with row number within particular group name and then you would filter row numbers lower or equal 2 in `HAVING` clause.

At the moment of writing django [does not support filtering based on window function result](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333) so you need to calculate row in the first query and filter `People` in the second query.

Following code is based on [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234076/7320870) but it implements limiting number of rows to be returned per `group_name`.

```py
from django.db.models import F, When, Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber

person_ids = {
    pk
    for pk, row_no_in_group in Person.objects.annotate(
        row_no_in_group=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(), 
            partition_by=[F('group_name')],
            order_by=['group_name', F('age').desc(), 'person']
        )
    ).values_list('id', 'row_no_in_group')
    if row_no_in_group <= 2
}
filtered_persons = Person.objects.filter(id__in=person_ids)
```

For following state of `Person` table

```
>>> Person.objects.order_by('group_name', '-age', 'person').values_list('group_name', 'age', 'person')
<QuerySet [(1, 19, 'Brian'), (1, 17, 'Brett'), (1, 14, 'Teresa'), (1, 13, 'Sydney'), (2, 20, 'Daniel'), (2, 18, 'Maureen'), (2, 14, 'Vincent'), (2, 12, 'Carlos'), (2, 11, 'Kathleen'), (2, 11, 'Sandra')]>
```

queries above return

```
>>> filtered_persons.order_by('group_name', '-age', 'person').values_list('group_name', 'age', 'person')
<QuerySet [(1, 19, 'Brian'), (1, 17, 'Brett'), (2, 20, 'Daniel'), (2, 18, 'Maureen')]>
```